Azure Data Factory(Change Column name in source dataset)
I am using Adf Data flow. In the source dataset I have a column name called '@url' which is coming from the blob. Now when I debug the pipeline I get the error:
ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'url'. I know that it is happening because of the @ sign at the start of the cloumn name url.
But I do not know how to fix it. Any suggestion?
I want to remove the @ from the column name @url in source , so that I do not get the error while debugging the adf pipeline.

The easiest way to do this would be a SELECT activity with a rule.
Add a Select task after your source. Deselect Auto mapping, and click +Add mapping. Enter the following values:

The column value true() indicates you want to apply the rule to all column names.
In the "Name as" rule, $$ refers to the column name value, so for each column name it removes all @ symbols.
For more complex scenarios, you can also use regexReplace.
I recommend you use the expression builder to code these items:


It needs to be changed in the source. I have tried to change it later but it still gives the same error as @url still exist in the source.
